# Mapping stream in DTO or passing mapped value to DTO separately?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-stream, dto

In my Spring Boot app, I use Java Stream API and map entity values to DTO as shown below:

```
public RecipeResponse findById(Long id) {
    return recipeRepository.findById(id)
            .map(RecipeResponse::new)
            .orElseThrow(() -> {
                return new NoSuchElementFoundException("Not found");
            });
}
```

But my response has also a list and I map this list in the following DTO:

```
@Data
public class RecipeResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredients;

    public RecipeResponse(Recipe recipe) {
        this.id = recipe.getId();
        this.title = recipe.getTitle();
        this.ingredients = recipe.getRecipeIngredients().stream().map(RecipeIngredientResponse::new).toList();
    }
}
```

I am not sure if it is a good or a proper idea to map the stream in DTO. I think maybe it would be a more proper way to pass `List<RecipeIngredientResponse>` from service method to this DTO constructor instead of mapping it in DTO as shown above. What is the most proper way for this scenario?

**Update:** I followed this approach:

```
@Data
public class RecipeResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredients;

    public RecipeResponse(Recipe recipe, List<RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredients) {
        this.id = recipe.getId();
        this.title = recipe.getTitle();
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }
}
```

```
public RecipeResponse findById(Long id) {
    return recipeRepository.findById(id)
            .map(recipe -> new RecipeResponse(
                    recipe,
                    recipe.getRecipeIngredients().stream().map(RecipeIngredientResponse::new).toList()))
            .orElseThrow(() -> {return new NoSuchElementFoundException("Not found");
            });
}
```

Comment: I would move the mapping logic inside the constructor to the service function, and the mapping would happen in the stream. This way you keep separated dtos and entities. I have to say tho, I don't think the way it is now is wrong, it is a matter of preferences I guess. The only thing I don't get is, why a "getById" method returns a stream? Isn't it supposed to return just one object?

Comment: Thanks, getById returns one object, but there is a list inside this object and the stream is related to this list. According to your comment, should I pass 2 separate object as `Recipe` and `List<RecipeIngredientResponse>` ?

Comment: I would not use the constructor, I would use setters. Also, the stream is not related to the list inside RecipeResponse, I don't think you need a stream there, maybe an optional.

Comment: @scatolone What are you trying to explain? Could you please post an example and share your suggestion?b On the other hand, without using stream, how can I map the fields properly?

Answer (score 0):

In order to follow SOLID principles and have some clear separation of responsibilities and make the code decoupled and easier to test, the recommended approach is to extract the conversion logic into a Converter.

```java
public interface Converter<IN, OUT> {
    OUT convert(IN input);
}
```

Example implementation for converting Recipe to RecipeResponse:

```java
public class RecipeResponseConverter implements Converter<Recipe, RecipeResponse> {
    private final Converter<RecipeIngredient, RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredientConverter;

    public RecipeResponseConverter(
        Converter<RecipeIngredient, RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredientConverter
    ) {
        this.ingredientConverter = ingredientConverter;
    }

    @Override
    public RecipeResponse convert(Recipe input) {
        var response = new RecipeResponse();
        response.setId(input.getId());
        response.setTitle(input.getTitle());
        response.setIngredients(input
                .getRecipeIngredients()
                .stream()
                .map(ingredientConverter::convert)
                .toList()
        );
        return response;
    }
}
```

Dependency Injection can be used to inject the recipe converter into the service class and to inject the ingredient converter into the recipe converter without coupling the implementations.

Please note how easy it is, using this approach, to test the various cases for converting a recipe without knowing the details of how an ingredient should be converted since that ingredient converter can just be mocked.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have 2 questions.

Comment: **1.** Can I also achieve this approach you suggested using ModelMapper?

Comment: **2.** Can you have a look at my update in the question. Is it ok as I moved the mapping the related field to the service method and make the DTO constructor clean? What do you think (if I do not use mapper)?

Comment: 1. Definitely yes. The implementation of the Converter interface can call ModelMapper instead of converting field by field. Alternatively, you can inject the ModelMapper directly instead of using the extra Converter interface, but bear in mind this couples your code more to that third-party library. Changing it in the future (e.g. for performance reasons let's say) would require more effort. Some examples of this at: https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper-lists.

Comment: 2. This new approach looks more decoupled than the previous one, so yes. I'd still recommend the use of a separate converter for isolated testing, but this is also ok for smaller scenarios.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, voted up. On the other hand, I always prefer using generic solutions and now I am looking for choosing the most proper one between 2 options: **1-** Using ModelMapper with a generic solution, **2-** Using Converter with a generic solution. Here is my question, would you consider sharing your suggestions?

Comment: [Mapping Entity and DTO using a generic solution with ModelMapper or Converter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75506927/mapping-entity-and-dto-using-a-generic-solution-with-modelmapper-or-converter)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

```
@Data
public class RecipeResponse {

    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private List<RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredients;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public List<RecipeIngredientResponse> getIngredients() {
        return ingredients;
    }

    public void setIngredients(List<RecipeIngredientResponse> ingredients) {
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
    }

}
```

---

```
public RecipeResponse findById(Long id) {

    return recipeRepository.findById(id).map(recipe -> {

        RecipeResponse recipeResponse = new RecipeResponse();
        recipeResponse.setId(id);
        recipeResponse.setTitle(recipe.getTitle());

        recipeResponse.setIngredients(
                recipe.getRecipeIngredients().stream().map((recipeIngredient) -> {
                    RecipeIngredientResponse recipeIngredientResponse = new RecipeIngredientResponse();
                    // set the RecipeIngredientResponse properties here
                    return recipeIngredientResponse;
                }).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        return new RecipeResponse();
    }).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementFoundException("Not found"));
}
```

I'm suggesting this solution because it decouples entities from dtos. Furthermore, I think that the mapping logic should not be inside the dto, dto should just hold the data.

I know it looks more verbose than the solution you posted, but I have a couple of suggestions in this regard. I would use a library like [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to get rid of getters and setters in the dto classes. Also, I would use a mapping framework, like [DozerMapper](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer), that would allow to map easily, with one/few lines, objects of different classes if their properties names are the same.