# Mapping Entity <-> DTO using a generic solution with ModelMapper or Converter?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapping, converters, modelmapper

In my Spring boot apps, I use a custom class for mapping from entity to dto or vice versa. On the other hand, I know there are some better options e.g. ModelMapper or Converter class.

After my searches, I have seen some good examples as shown below:

[Automatically Mapping DTO to Entity on Spring Boot APIs](https://auth0.com/blog/automatically-mapping-dto-to-entity-on-spring-boot-apis/)

It sounds good, but as I have no previous experience, I wanted to be clarified about some points before proceeding. Could you help me please?

**1.** Is that solution is a proper ModelMapper example and can I also apply that approach for mapping entity to DTO?

**2.** What about implementing Converter interface without using a 3rd party library? Can I also build a generic mechanism using Converter interface?

Note: I also considered using MapStruct or JMapper, but ModelMapper sounds easier to use and for this reason I decided to use ModelMapper. But if you have some suggestion that clearly shows one of them has more advantegous, feel free to share your suggestions. I could also consider to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From my expérience, this is my suggestion. You have 1 entity and 1 entityDTO.
You make a constructor of entity that takes in parameter the entity DTO. Then you make a constructor for entityDTO that takes in parameter an entity.
Finnaly, you create a mapper class for a given element that will use the 2 constructors to generate what you need. Here is an exemple :

Entity.java :

```
    @Entity
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Table(name="entity")
    public class Entity{
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id_entity;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;
        
    public Entity(EntityDTO entityDTO){
       this.setId_entity(entityDTO.getId_entity())
       this.setName(entityDTO.getName())
    }
   }
```

EntityDTO.java :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class EntityDTO{
    private Long id_entity;
    private String name;

   public EntityDTO(Entity entity){
      this.setId_Entity(entity.getId_entity())
      this.setName(entity.getName())
   }

}
```

EntityMapper.java :

```
    @Component
    public class EntityMapper{
        public EntityDTO toDto(Entity entity){
            return new EntityDTO(entity);
        }
      
        public Entity toEntity(EntityDTO entityDTO){
            return new Entity(entityDTO);
        }
}
```

These anotations are from lombok library, used for time saving :

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
```

Then you can just make requests to Database to get entities, and place the flow of answers through the mapper to convert them to EntityDTO and send them to where ever you need. In your controller :

```
@Autowired
EntityMapper mapper;
```

In your functions, you can return :

```
service.getEntities().stream.map(mapper::toDTO).collect(Collectors.toList();
```

Comment: Sounds good, voted up. But instead of creating everything from scratch, what about using some pre-defined interfaces e.g. Converter interface?

Comment: Hey, in my humble opinion is better to stay simple for this kind of problem.